# How to add data instead of replacing it using requests, Python, and Firebase

Tags: python, rest, firebase, python-requests

I'm using the `requests` module to get and set data in Firebase. Say I have an existing firebase, http://mytest.firebaseio.com, that looks like this

```
|somewhere
  |--test1
    |--exists: 1
```

And I want to add data to it, so it looks like:

```
|somewhere
  |--test1
    |--exists: 1
    |--arrived: 1
```

My instinct is to use `put()`, such as:

```
r = requests.put('http://mytest.firebaseio.com/test1.json',data='{"arrived":1}')
```

But this results in *erasing* the `exists: 1` in addition to adding the `arrived: 1`, such as:

```
|somewhere
  |--test1
    |--arrived: 1
```

How can I add `arrived: 1` without erasing `exists: 1`?

Comment: This seems unnecessary. Could you explain the use case, and why you can't just put directly to the arrived path? (e.g. `requests.put('http://mytest.firebaseio.com/test1/arrived.json',data='1')`

Comment: I didn't realize I could do that, as I thought the data had to be a complete JSON obj pair. Yes, that may make more sense than the `patch()`

Comment: If it needs to be a complete JSON pair (I'm also not positive here) then this should work: `.put('https://.../arrived.json',data='{".value": 1}')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html#patch-updating-data):

> You can update specific children at a location without overwriting existing data with a PATCH request. Named children in the data being written with PATCH will be written, but omitted children will not be deleted. This is equivalent to the update( ) function.

So you want to be using `requests.patch()` instead of `requests.put()`.